# null value for notesdocument returned

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am restructuring an application I have. In the current design I have all logic for a person object in a single class (Person) but I have understood that it is better that that Person class should only describe the data-model and that all actions around the Person data-model should better be handled by a Controller class (e.g. PersonController).

When I move such code from Person to PersonController class I get instead of a NotesDocument null returned.

Below is some sample code:

```
public void getByUnid(String unid) throws NotesException{
        Database db = dao.getDatabase();
        Document doc = db.getDocumentByUNID(unid);      
        if (null == doc) {
            //doc not found
        } else {
            //doc found
            prepareDoc(doc);
        }
        doc.recycle();
        db.recycle();
    }


    private void prepareDoc(Document doc) throws NotesException {
            fname = doc.getItemValueString("fname");    
//...get other fields
    }
```

Normally I would call the Person.getByUnid(id) and it works fine. When I call PersonController.getByUnid(id) the doc value is null.

I make the call in the beforeonpageload event in an xpage e.g. person.xsp:

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:

var id = paramValues.get("UNID");

if (id != null){
    PersonController.getByUnid(id.toString());
}

else{
    Person.create();
}}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

What am I doing wrong or should I include the Person class in the PersonController class?

Comment: Is db not null? does the unid exist? does the user have access to the document?

Comment: I think we need a bit more info.  When the getByUnid was in the person class, it was loading all of the data from the doc, which comes from the db, which is loaded by the dao.  Does the personController have a non-null dao?

Comment: I think the problem is that the Person object does not exist when I try to read values from it e.g. Person.fname. Before the Person object was already loaded. So I wonder how I can intialize a Person object from the PersonController with the values loaded?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can get a direct answer without showing all the relevant code.  For example, We can't see where "dao" comes from in this case.

But barring that.  I would question the need for a "PersonController".  That may indeed be a more "Java Purist" method, which is fine, but if you have something working without it then I'd say just go with what works and refactor later if need be.

Below is a person class I have from a rather old example, but to this day I still use the same concepts.  I have various "loader" methods which are responsible to get the document, then that gets passed to a load values method to populate the object.  The save method basically reverses the process.

So again - if you post more code we can look at the original question.

There's more java and XPages examples at NotesIn9.com or XPages.TV if you need them.

```
package com.notesin9.examples;
import java.io.Serializable;
import lotus.domino.*;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import com.ZetaOne.util.*;


public class Person implements Serializable, Comparable<Person> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String city;
    private boolean readOnly;
    private String unid;
    private Boolean newNote;
    private String unique;

    public Person() {

    }

    public void create() throws NotesException{
        // System.out.println("Creating New");
        newNote = true;     
        JSFUtil jsfUtil = new JSFUtil();
        Session session = jsfUtil.getSession();
        unique = String.valueOf(session.evaluate("@Unique").get(0));
    }

    public void loadByKey(String key) throws NotesException {
        // Loading by unique key to the document
        JSFUtil jsfUtil = new JSFUtil();
        Session session = jsfUtil.getSession();

        Database currentDB = jsfUtil.getCurrentDatabase();
        View mainView = currentDB.getView("byKey");
        Document doc = mainView.getDocumentByKey(key);

        if (null == doc) {
            System.out.println("Document not found");
        } else {
            loadValues(doc);
        }

        doc.recycle();
        mainView.recycle();

    }
    public void loadByUnid(String unid) throws NotesException{
        // Loading by document unid
        JSFUtil jsfUtil = new JSFUtil();
        Session session = jsfUtil.getSession();

        Database currentDB = jsfUtil.getCurrentDatabase();
        Document doc = currentDB.getDocumentByUNID(unid);

        if (null == doc) {
            System.out.println("Document not found");
        } else {
            loadValues(doc);
        }
        doc.recycle();

    }

    public void loadValues(Document doc) throws NotesException {
        firstName = doc.getItemValueString("firstName");
        lastName = doc.getItemValueString("lastName");
        city = doc.getItemValueString("city");
        newNote = false;
        unique = doc.getItemValueString("unique");
        unid = doc.getUniversalID();
        // System.out.println("Person Loaded");
    }


    public void save() throws NotesException {
        JSFUtil jsfUtil = new JSFUtil();
        Session session = jsfUtil.getSession();

        Database currentDB = jsfUtil.getCurrentDatabase();
        Document doc = null;  // PlaceHolder

        if (newNote) {
            // True means never been saved
            System.out.println("This is a new Doc");
            doc = currentDB.createDocument();
            doc.replaceItemValue("form", "person");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is an existing doc");
            doc = currentDB.getDocumentByUNID(unid);

        }
        // Common elements to save
        doc.replaceItemValue("firstName", firstName);
        doc.replaceItemValue("lastName", lastName);
        doc.replaceItemValue("city", city);
        doc.replaceItemValue("unique", unique);

        // System.out.println("about to save");
        doc.save();
        doc.recycle();
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public boolean isReadOnly() {
        return readOnly;
    }

    public void setReadOnly(boolean readOnly) {
        this.readOnly = readOnly;
    }

    public String getUnid() {
        return unid;
    }

    public void setUnid(String unid) {
        this.unid = unid;
    }

    public Boolean getNewNote() {
        return newNote;
    }

    public void setNewNote(Boolean newNote) {
        this.newNote = newNote;
    }

    public String getUnique() {
        return unique;
    }

    public void setUnique(String unique) {
        this.unique = unique;
    }

    public int compareTo(Person comparePerson) {
         // Default by Last name Sort
        String personName1 = this.getLastName().toUpperCase() + ", " + this.getFirstName().toUpperCase();
        String personName2 = comparePerson.getLastName().toUpperCase() + ", " + this.getFirstName().toUpperCase();

        //ascending order
        return personName1.compareTo(personName2);

        //descending order
        //return cityName2.compareTo(cityName1);

    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I used that approach at first and that was running fine. The problem arose when I moved the logic to load a person document from the Person class to the PersonController class. I understand that in this new way the Person object is never initialized so I can not call properties from it e.g. Person.fname / Person.getFname() so I wonder how I can do that from the PersonController class? (load Person object from PersonController class).

Comment: I think the answer is described somewhere in this post http://dontpanic82.blogspot.se/2012/05/using-java-reflection-and-domino-form.html . in the contructor for the personcontroller I should instantiate the person class e.g. this.person = new Person(); some work to do...

Comment: You're welcome.  I guess if you had it working I'm not quite seeing the benefit of moving to a PersonController class.  I'm a big fan of pageControllers but I don't get the need for a PersonController yet.  I'd sure be interested in seeing your entire code for these 2 classes either here or email me over at notesin9.com if you were interested.

Comment: You could have the person class as inner class to the controller

Comment: @DavidLeedy I believe this is a best-practice rule in MVC architecture so you have another layer for separating your model from your controller.

Comment: It might be..  I've not looked into true MVC...  But in an XPages implementation to me...  what you really need is your dataSource of course.  Then an object to represent that data, and then a pageController to handle the core logic on the page.  I don't know where this fits with pure MVC - BUT it works very well for XPages.